# Why the surfeit of close votes for questions on the Semantics of French Prepositions?

Tags: discussion

Some of my recent questions (as of 2016/1/23) have generated close votes and downvotes, but I do not see a comment advising or explaining, and would be grate to know, why.

While my questions concern French, they do pertain to Linguistics, and are more difficult than French questions that can be posed on French SE. Examples:

1. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/15622/5306,
2. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15651/semantics-of-%C3%A0-vs-de-after-an-adjective-and-after-a-noun,
3. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15635/how-is-renoncer-%C3%A0-monovalent-vision-rather-than-ambivalent-vision

Comment: Can you explain how this could possibly generalize to linguistics rather than being just a question about the meaning of a particular French expression? Since your concern is author unclarity, have you tried directly asking the authors what they mean? People do that all the time.

Comment: @user6726 Thanks for your constructive last two sentences. About your 1st: I asked about the preposition 'de'; so it is not ` just a question about the meaning of a particular French expression`?

Answer (score 2):

I personally voted to close some of them because they were:

1. Potentially duplicates because they all deal with the grammatical and semantic differences of *à* and *de*
2. Also potentially duplicates because they all ask about one single linguistics paper
3. Borderline language specific

Certainly they are much more appropriate for this StackExchange site as opposed to the French SE, but in light of the first two points, they really could have been condensed down quite a bit more, perhaps only in to one question, instead of asked across several questions.

Comment: 4. How could they `condensed down quite a bit more,`? I do not see how. 5. Sorry, but your 1 and 2 appear to generalise my questions  too hastily; the semantic differences of à and de constitute a topic on its own, as evidenced by the plethora of research papers on it. 6. The commonality of the source(s) for questions does not make the questions duplicates.

Comment: Have you been able to read my reply above?

Comment: I think in part we're going to have to agree to disagree.  I think, given the size of the Linguistics SE, they just overlap with one another too much with one another. I would second the recommendation of @user6726: if we haven't done a good enough job of making them more clear to you, perhaps you should contact the original authors.